# Loop to count event numbers in a range always returns 1

Tags: c++, loops

I'm need of some advice and helpful pointers to get me in the right direction. My function is intended to calculate how many even numbers there are between input a and input b.

```
int evens(int a, int b)
{
    int p = 0;
    for(int i=a; i<=b; i++)
    {
        if(i % 2==0)
            ++p;
         return (p);
    }
}
```

Logically, this function makes sense to me and it's easy to understand what's going on. However, when I run the program it returns P as being "1" no matter what the input #'s are. This leads me to believe that the loop is for some reason only run once and then that's it.

Comment: (FWIW: this particular problem can be solved without loops.)

Comment: You could calculate the answer without looping... take the difference of the two numbers, divide by two and adjust the result considering the two ends of the range.

Comment: The formula of difference divided by 2 can also fall apart with integer overflows if you have big numbers.

Comment: Yeah, and it's also flawed because if the input are two odd numbers, like 5 + 19, it will output 14/2+1=8 and there are actually just 7 even numbers between 5 and 19.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're returning too early. Put it outside of the loop.

Could rewrite it like this though:

```
int evens(int a, int b) {
    if(a != b)
        return ((b-a)/2)+1; //I can't think straight, I don't know why
    else {
        if(a % 2 == 0)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: And we are back online! That was a strange outage :) I've actually tried that before posting here and it returns the same result....

Comment: @PatrickNommensen It likely *won't* be the same result (for a suitable a and b) .. make sure the files are correctly saved before recompiling.

Comment: It turns out, my problem was that in the 'main' I called the function before calling for a and b (the 2 # inputs). I wasn't aware that the call had to happen afterwards. Thanks!